# FireBase Rule not working with auth.uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules

I`m trying to set a Firebase rule that will grant access to R/W, if the $uid is equal to auth.uid.

**This is an example of my DB structure:**

[image]

**The first rule configuration I tried:**

```
{
"rules": {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
}
```

**I also have tried this way (include the path of the root):**

```
{
    "rules": {
        "AppName-46ed8":{
            "$uid" : {
                ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I`m following the Firebase instructions and this rules pass the simulator.

I`m not getting the instance with snapshot from Firebase when these rules are in place.

If I use the default "Unsafe" rules as follows, everything works as it should (but is open to threat of hacking):

```
    {
    "rules": {
        ".read": true, ".write":true
             }
     }
```

Please advice.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Im not getting any response from Firebase when these rules are in place"?

Comment: I`m not getting the instance with snapshot

Comment: Do you get the instance without rules?

Comment: Yes, it`s working without the rules.

Comment: And the user is definitely authenticated and signed in?

Comment: Yes. They match.

Comment: show your method how you write to the database

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4wwhR2eA

Answer (score 2):

The follow it should work:

> These rules require authentication
>
> Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != false",
    ".write": "auth != false",
    "Users": {
      "$id":{
        ".read": "auth.uid == $id",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $id",
      }
    },
  }
}
```