# Google Firebase RealtimeDB Rules not working with UID

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

We are trying to write rules for a google firebase realtimedb that only allows users to read and write to a location that is their own UID when they are authenticated.
Here is our current rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

And our DB structure:

```js
{
  "W48941DIDOIJ30" : {
    "subscription" : {
      "premium" : true
    },
    "watchlist" : []
  }
}
```

When we attempt to make a get request for the watchlist or subscription for an authenticated user with the same UID we are hit with a 401 error. What gives?

Edit:
Here is our method that calls the realtimeDB (we are using NUXT.js)

```js
async getData () {
      const messageRef = this.$fire.database.ref(this.currentUser.uid)
      const idToken = await this.currentUser.uid // or this.currentUser.getIdToken()
      const response = await axios.get(
        messageRef.toString() + '.json',
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}` }
        }
      )
      this.$store.commit('ON_WATCHLIST_CHANGE', response.data.watchlist)
      if (response.data.watchlist.companies.includes(this.$route.params.company) || response.data.watchlist.drugs.includes(this.$route.params.comound)) {
        this.$store.commit('CURRENT_PAGE_CHECK', true)
      }
    },
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the minimal, exact code that reproduces the problem? Please make sure that the code shows that the conditions in the rules are met, for example by logging the UID right before accessing the databae.\

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Just added the method that calls the DB. Thanks!

Comment: @Joaquin684 Please add the answer if the problem is resolved.

Comment: @AbhiChitrapu I think Joaquin was saying that they've updated the question with the requested information, not that they've found a solution

Answer (score 1):

When you make a database call using `axios` directly, you need to make sure that you pass in your user's ID token too:

```
async getData () {
  const messageRef = this.$fire.database.ref(this.currentUser.uid)
  const idToken = await this.$fire.auth.currentUser.getIdToken() // or this.currentUser.getIdToken()
  const response = await axios.get(
    messageRef.toString() + '.json',
    {
      headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}` }
    }
  )
  this.$store.commit('ON_WATCHLIST_CHANGE', response.data.watchlist)
}
```

If you omit the token, you'll just be considered an anonymous user by the Firebase servers.

You can also handle this using an [axios interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to automatically add the ID token each time a request is made.

Comment: Thank you for solving this part of the issue; we now have the authorization appearing in the request header, as I attached in edit 2. However, we are still getting a 401 error due to the real-time DB rules.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this below structure for your rules which is also mentioned in this [Google document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#the_auth_variable) and check if it works.

```
{ 
 "rules": {
     "users": {
        "$uid": {
              ".write":  "$uid === auth.uid", ".read":  "auth.uid == $uid"
          } 
       } 
    }
}
```

You can also refer to this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049139/15774177) that I found, which might be useful.

Comment: @Joaquin684, did this answer your question?